Move labels close to "axis" on pyplot "radar_chart"
I use matplotlib and geopandas to plot a map.
Now I'd like to plot additional information on top of this map, e.g. using radar charts or pie charts.
I got this sweet function, which creates radar charts for me
def radar_chart(ax, data, categories, color, label_fontsize=8):
    N = len(categories)
    angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False).tolist()

    data = np.concatenate((data, [data[0]]))
    angles += [angles[0]]

    ax.fill(angles, data, color=color, alpha=0.25)
    ax.plot(angles, data, color=color, linewidth=2)

    ax.set_xticks(angles[:-1])
    ax.set_xticklabels(categories, fontsize=label_fontsize)  # Schriftgröße anpassen

    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

which looks pretty well, as long as the radar charts are fairly large.

Yet, this size is unhandy, for they would cover most of my map. However, if I plot them smaller, they look riddiculous, since the padding between the axis and the labels is way out of proportion, especially if I use an adjusted font size.

Is there a way to change this padding?
If I can not specify this padding, I figgured I might just plot the subplot in a larger size, so the proportions within the subplot look nice and then scale it down, so it fits in the main plot.
Yet, I failed to find a way to do that. A difficulty might be, that scale has another meaning in the context of matplotlib than resizing images...
Can I scale subplots as in downscaling an image?

The answer to the first question:
  ax.tick_params(pad=-3)

I guess I missed, that obviously my "axes" are not the axes but rather the ticks on the circular x-axe instead.
This solves the problem, and the second question becomes obsolete for now.
